# How does http://jwt.io retrieve keycloak signing key?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

I'm experimenting with Keycloak OAUTH server (7.0.11), and it seems to be working well but I'm still confused on how I can validate the tokens it generates. For example, I generated an `id_token` and pasted it into http://jwt.io which displays a well-formed payload and the following header:

```json
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "<my-key-id>"
}
```

It also displays "Signature Verified", and somehow retrieved the valid RSASHA256 public key into the appropriate form in the jwt.io HTML page.

I want to be able to validate the token myself by checking the signature. My understanding is that I do this by retrieving the public signing key from the keycloak server JWKS Certificate-Endpoint: https://<server+port>/auth/realms/core/protocol/openid-connect/certs. The resulting object contains one key:

```json
{
      "kid":"<matches-my-key-id-above>",
      "kty":"RSA",
      "alg":"RS256",
      "use":"sig",
...
      "x5c":["<snip>"],
...
}
```

Great that the `kid`s match, but the value in `x5c` does *not* match the publickey displayed by http://jwt.io, and when I paste my `x5c` value in its place the form says the signature is invalid. According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517 the value should already be base64-encoded (and looks like it is to me as well).

Unfortunately I'm not able to narrow this down to a nicely targeted question. But ...

- Why isn't the key reported by my keycloak auth server validating the token -- especially since the `kid` from the token and the only JWKS key matches?
- How is http://jwt.io finding any publickey to check the signature if my header does not include any `jku` to query from?

TIA everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Solved this a while ago but forgot to update this thread: the trick is to query the main Issuer Realm: `https://<server>:<port>/auth/realms/<realm>` which *does* return the realm public-key:

```
{
  "realm": "testrealm",
  "public_key": "<THIS BIT HERE SNIPPED>",
  "token-service": "https://.../auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect",
  "account-service": "https://.../auth/realms/testrealm/account",
  "tokens-not-before": 0
}
```

That public-key is what signs al the tokens *not* the x509 certificate returned by the realm JWKS endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [blog post](https://authguidance.com/home/mainindex/) that describes the process. Everything you've done sounds right except for surrounding the key with well known delimiters such as these, before pasting it into jwt.io.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
token signing public key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Of course, [programmatic solutions](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts) use libraries that do this type of thing automatically.

Key details could be slightly different for Keycloak, such as this:

- BEGIN / END RSA KEY

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding, I will check your blog. Unfortunately I pasted my cert into the form leaving the existing BEGIN/END delimiter lines that were already there for the key that was apparently working. What baffles me is that the content between those delimitter lines were completely different key values.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting explanation -- but not quite an answer -- that I've found: on the Keycloak server realm server settings, there is a Public Key and a Certificate.

The Public Key is indeed the correct value for verifying my access tokens, and what shows up in the jwt.io form when I load my access token (still don't know how it's retrieving that).

The Certificate is what is being returned when I make an HTTP request to the Certificates Endpoint/JWKS.

So I shouldn't be validating my access tokens via the certificate? Or is there another set of arguments I can use to verify via a certificate rather than public key?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of how **jwt.io** knows your public key is that at the moment you paste it into **jwt.io**, the javascript running on that page takes and uses the **iss field** inside your JWT:

```
"iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm"
```

Now, since you are probably running local keycloak on port 8080, the page triggers calls to the following URLs locally:

*http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration*
and
*http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs*

These calls return an array of keys which the page in **jwt.io** process, it extracts the correct key according to the kid defined in the jwt and puts the whole json part of that key in the public key part of this decoding page.
That’s how it "knows" your public keys.

You can try to take down your local keycloak server, paste your jwt into **jwt.io** and realize that your verification will fail.